# MySQL - Shrinking table from hourly to daily for "a week ago" rows

Tags: mysql

I have a statistics table which shows impressions and clicks by site, country and break down by hour.

However, since the table size grows incredibly high once a new site is added, i want to run a query/transaction once a day to replace all "week ago" data into date format and remove the precision of an hour.

So i figured that i need a transaction for that, but i am not sure how can i "organized" that in a transaction, since the rows that i want to insert are a query result from i want to delete.

This is what i want to insert:

```
SELECT DATE(date), host, country, sum(impressions) as impressions, sum(clicks) as clicks 
FROM Reports WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-04-30 00:00:00'
AND '2015-04-30 23:59:59' group by host, country
```

And this is what i want to delete:

```
DELETE FROM Reports WHERE
date BETWEEN '2015-04-30 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-30 23:59:59'
```

I also want to mention that i have a UNIQUE constraint on date,host,country.

Thanks.

Comment: So your `date` field (which you should probably escape with backticks for safety), is a datetime data type? Also, you should be GROUPing on the DATE(`date`) as well.

Comment: @Strawberry, `date` is a reserved word in MySQL. And I suppose "escape" was the wrong word choice. As a general rule, I enclose all field and table names in backticks anyway, to: (1) make it easier to find field references later when searching code, and (2) in case it happens to collide with a future keyword.

Comment: Why would i want to GROUPing on the DATE(date) ?

Comment: @yosiweinreb, Oh yeah, I suppose with your WHERE range, it is not really necessary; but for your initial archiving, or if you ended up instead running  it on a weekly (or monthly) basis for the days in the preceding week (or month), you would have issues without it unless you ran the queries for each day separately.

Comment: @Uueerdo The list of reserved words is publicly available. Date is not amongst them. (I think 'escape' is the right word btw)

Comment: @Strawberry, technically not reserved, but it is a keyword (it would probably be reserved if MySQL didn't make an exception for it).  From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html, "MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted ..."

Comment: @Uueerdo I have a particular aversion to backticks but anyway, each to their own - and your point about the GROUP BY clause is spot on.

Comment: Yeah, the "always backtick" is personal preference. Some people are concerned with portability issues (since it is only MySQL that uses them), but in my experience all but the simplest of queries need retested (and often partially rewritten) against different providers anyway.

Comment: Have you looked at the MySQL documentation for transactions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html